# Tensorflow on shared GPUs: how to automatically select the one that is unused

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, distributed-system

I have access through ssh to a cluster of n GPUs. Tensorflow automatically gave them names gpu:0,...,gpu:(n-1).

Others have access too and sometimes they take random gpus.
I did not place any `tf.device()` explicitely because that is cumbersome and even if I selected gpu number j and that someone is already on gpu number j that would be problematic.

I would like to go throuh the gpus usage and find the first that is unused and use only this one.
I guess someone could parse the output of `nvidia-smi` with bash and get a variable i and feed that variable i to the tensorflow script as the number of the gpu to use.

I have never seen any example of this. I imagine it is a pretty common problem. What would be the simplest way to do that ? Is a pure tensorflow one available ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not aware of pure-TensorFlow solution. The problem is that existing place for TensorFlow configurations is a Session config. However, for GPU memory, a GPU memory pool is shared for all TensorFlow sessions within a process, so Session config would be the wrong place to add it, and there's no mechanism for process-global config (but there should be, to also be able to configure process-global Eigen threadpool). So you need to do on on a process level by using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable.

Something like this:

```
import subprocess, re

# Nvidia-smi GPU memory parsing.
# Tested on nvidia-smi 370.23

def run_command(cmd):
    """Run command, return output as string."""
    output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
    return output.decode("ascii")

def list_available_gpus():
    """Returns list of available GPU ids."""
    output = run_command("nvidia-smi -L")
    # lines of the form GPU 0: TITAN X
    gpu_regex = re.compile(r"GPU (?P<gpu_id>\d+):")
    result = []
    for line in output.strip().split("\n"):
        m = gpu_regex.match(line)
        assert m, "Couldnt parse "+line
        result.append(int(m.group("gpu_id")))
    return result

def gpu_memory_map():
    """Returns map of GPU id to memory allocated on that GPU."""

    output = run_command("nvidia-smi")
    gpu_output = output[output.find("GPU Memory"):]
    # lines of the form
    # |    0      8734    C   python                                       11705MiB |
    memory_regex = re.compile(r"[|]\s+?(?P<gpu_id>\d+)\D+?(?P<pid>\d+).+[ ](?P<gpu_memory>\d+)MiB")
    rows = gpu_output.split("\n")
    result = {gpu_id: 0 for gpu_id in list_available_gpus()}
    for row in gpu_output.split("\n"):
        m = memory_regex.search(row)
        if not m:
            continue
        gpu_id = int(m.group("gpu_id"))
        gpu_memory = int(m.group("gpu_memory"))
        result[gpu_id] += gpu_memory
    return result

def pick_gpu_lowest_memory():
    """Returns GPU with the least allocated memory"""

    memory_gpu_map = [(memory, gpu_id) for (gpu_id, memory) in gpu_memory_map().items()]
    best_memory, best_gpu = sorted(memory_gpu_map)[0]
    return best_gpu
```

You can then put it in `utils.py` and set GPU in your TensorFlow script before first `tensorflow` import. IE

```
import utils
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = str(utils.pick_gpu_lowest_memory())
import tensorflow
```

Comment: Thanks for this brillant answer !

Comment: So apparently `nvidia-smi` can give mismatching device numbers in some situation, it looks like you have to combine it `lspci` to get the correct numbers, as discussed in [152](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/152#issuecomment-273555972)

Comment: I will check it out thanks ! But so far your solution seemed to be working fine for me !

Comment: If it stops working, the workaround it set environment variable: export CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID

Comment: I saw that on github. Thanks again !

Answer (score 10):

An implementation along the lines of Yaroslav Bulatov's solution is available on https://github.com/bamos/setGPU.